Deadbolt keeps chipping door frame, is there a solution?
If our deadbolt is slightly thrown as the door shuts, it chips the door frame. We've repeatedly filled it in, but it recurs easily. It seems only latch plates, not deadbolts, come with the protective lip.
I've looked at "latch protectors" but those protect the door, not the frame. 

Replace the deadbolt.  It should have 2 positions, in or out.  It has lost its detent that keeps it in.  You can make them be partially out, but you should have to work at it.

This is the right answer. A quality deadbolt will have a snap type feel as it gets to one end or the other of its range of travel.

And the last thing you need is for the deadbolt to bounce out just enough to lock the door, so that's why those bolts normally don't come out loose like this.

Replace the deadbolt with what?  In the US, building codes require a minimum of two exit doors SO unless you can find the same model, you would be replacing all (2+) dead bolts or carry around multiple keys to the house.

@quill -- any competent locksmith can rekey or even cylinder swap a deadbolt to match an existing lock

@ThreePhaseEel - OK, in this specific case  the lock can be changed while not requiring a keying of other deadbolts - that's because it looks like Titan locks are still being sold.  Had it been some lock from a company long out of business - that would be a different matter.

@quill eventually locks wear out. Yes if it were too old and locks were not being made on the key style you would need to either have 2 keys or replace all the same-keyed locks.

Install a strike plate with a "lip" like the latch for the doorknob. It sticks out and prevents the deadbolt from striking the door frame.
You might have to shop around for the one that fits the deadbolt and door frame dimensions, but everything is pretty much common sizes.
This might get you started:
https://www.google.com/search?q=deadbolt+full+lip+strike+plate
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=full+lip+deadbolt+strike+plate

Don't close the door with the deadbolt out. Get the hand muscle habit learned to have the deadbolt handle fully rotated and withdrawn before the door is closed.
A quick confirmatory twist on the deadbolt handle will be learned easily.

Get a piece of angle metal, ideally brass-colored.  Screw it to the door jamb over the corner where the deadbolt is biting chunks out.  Now, when the deadbolt hits it, it'll bash against metal instead of wood.
Or solve the problem properly with a good deadbolt.
